# Programmatically Authenticate LDAP user in AEM

Tags: java, ldap, aem, apacheds

I've set up local LDAP server
Created user and group.
Configured LDAP in AEM config manager and synchronized the users and group.

Using, ExternalIdentityProvider as a service reference, I'm able to get list of LDAP users I.e. I am able to validate if the user is present in LDAP or not.

But, I'm not able to validate user credentials using authentic method of the above mentioned API.

Am I missing any configuration specifics or the approach that I'm using is wrong ?

Updated:

Authentication code:

```
@Reference
private ExternalIdentityProviderManager externalIdentityProviderManager;

final String externalId = request.getParameter("externalId");
final String externalPassword = request.getParameter("externalPassword");

final ExternalIdentityProvider idap = externalIdentityProviderManager.getProvider("ldap");
final SimpleCredentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials(externalId, externalPassword.toCharArray());
final ExternalUser externalUser = idap.authenticate(credentials);
```

Error thrown -

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to authenticate against LDAP server: INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: cn=steve+uid=steve+sn=jobs,dc=example,dc=com
```

Update:
Identity provider config

```
# Configuration created by Apache Sling JCR Installer
userPool.maxActive=L"8"
searchTimeout="60s"
host.name="localhost"
customattributes=[""]
adminPool.maxActive=L"8"
group.makeDnPath=B"false"
user.baseDN="ou\=Users,dc\=example,dc\=com"
group.objectclass=["groupOfNames"]
user.objectclass=["person"]
userPool.lookupOnValidate=B"true"
host.noCertCheck=B"false"
user.makeDnPath=B"true"
bind.dn="uid\=admin,ou\=system"
group.baseDN="ou\=Groups,dc\=example,dc\=com"
group.extraFilter=""
user.extraFilter=""
host.port=I"10389"
bind.password="secret"
adminPool.lookupOnValidate=B"true"
useUidForExtId=B"false"
group.nameAttribute="cn"
provider.name="ldap"
host.ssl=B"false"
host.tls=B"false"
user.idAttribute="uid"
group.memberAttribute="member"
```

Sync Handler

```
# Configuration created by Apache Sling JCR Installer
group.pathPrefix=""
user.dynamicMembership=B"false"
group.expirationTime="1d"
user.membershipExpTime="1h"
user.pathPrefix=""
user.propertyMapping=["profile/nt:primaryType\=\"nt:unstructured\"","profile/givenName\=cn","profile/rep:password\=userPassword"]
handler.name="syncHandlerDefault"
enableRFC7613UsercaseMappedProfile=B"false"
user.autoMembership=[""]
user.expirationTime="1h"
group.propertyMapping=[""]
group.autoMembership=[""]
user.disableMissing=B"false"
user.membershipNestingDepth=I"3"
```

External login

```
# Configuration created by Apache Sling JCR Installer
jaas.controlFlag="SUFFICIENT"
jaas.ranking=I"50"
sync.handlerName="syncHandlerDefault"
jaas.realmName=""
idp.name="ldap"
```

LDIF file for users

```
version: 1

dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Users

dn: cn=eden+sn=hazard+uid=eden,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: eden
sn: hazard
uid: eden
userPassword: {SSHA}O/t6ZRnWZTLhHla106Hp5nIWy85b0kgwNmeY3w==

dn: cn=rohit+sn=sharma+uid=rohit,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: rohit
sn: sharma
uid: rohit
userPassword: {SSHA}9fzIkizxYg3LGG8n0jf/tnpv//qiNlxtS6mnWg==

dn: cn=harry+uid=harry+sn=kane,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: harry
sn: kane
uid: harry
userPassword: {SSHA}WjNxB0ZDsmKfpjN0zwgsvDtZ4c/lHrIZXb7T2g==

dn: cn=cristiano+uid=cristiano+sn=ronaldo,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: cristiano
sn: ronaldo
uid: cristiano
userPassword: {SSHA}ykzpMLVAbK99hfbCwwGgmgcDVzDV/Kfl0TlA8Q==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LDAP Login you need 3 OSGi configs. The most difficult one, you already have.

- External Login Module (containing a reference to the next two)
- LDAP Identity Provider (how to access the LDAP)
- Sync Handler (mapping the LDAP data to AEM user data)

Here an example:

**org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModuleFactory-emea**

```
"jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
"jaas.ranking": "50",
"jaas.controlFlag": "SUFFICIENT",
"jaas.realmName": "",
"idp.name": "ldap-emea",
"sync.handlerName": "sync-emea"
```

**org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authentication.ldap.impl.LdapIdentityProvider-emea**

```
"jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
"provider.name": "ldap-emea",
"host.name": "ldap-emea.emea.mycompany.internal",
"host.port": "3269",
"host.ssl": true,
"host.tls": true,
"host.noCertCheck": false,
"bind.dn": "CN=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=emea,DC=dir",
"bind.password": "very secret",
"searchTimeout": "60s",
"adminPool.maxActive": "8",
"adminPool.lookupOnValidate": true,
"userPool.maxActive": "8",
"userPool.lookupOnValidate": true,
"user.baseDN": "DC=emea,DC=dir",
"user.objectclass": "user",
"user.idAttribute": "sAMAccountName",
"user.extraFilter": "xxx very specific LDAP query xxxxx",
"user.makeDnPath": false,
"group.baseDN": "OU=Groups,OU=Common,DC=emea,DC=dir",
"group.objectclass": "group",
"group.nameAttribute": "cn",
"group.extraFilter": "xxx very specific LDAP query xxxxx",
"group.makeDnPath": false,
"group.memberAttribute": "member",
"customattributes": []
```

**org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.DefaultSyncHandler-emea**

```
"jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
"handler.name": "sync-emea",
"user.expirationTime": "1h",
"user.autoMembership": [],
"user.propertyMapping": [
   "rep:fullname=cn",
   "profile/email=mail",
   "profile/familyName=sn",
   "profile/givenName=givenName",
   "profile/aboutMe=description",
   "profile/country=co",
   "profile/jobTitle=department",
   "profile/phoneNumber=telephoneNumber",
   "profile/mobile=mobile",
   "profile/postalCode=postalCode",
   "profile/street=streetAddress",
   "preferences/language=\"en\""
],
"user.pathPrefix": "my-company/emea",
"user.membershipExpTime": "1h",
"user.membershipNestingDepth": "3",
"group.expirationTime": "1d",
"group.autoMembership": [],
"group.propertyMapping": [
   "profile/givenName=name",
   "profile/aboutMe=description"
],
"group.pathPrefix": "my-company/nested/emea",
"user.dynamicMembership": false,
"user.disableMissing": false,
"enableRFC7613UsercaseMappedProfile": false
```

kind regards,
Alex

---

I additionally setup an Apache Directory Server and filled it with the sample data (Sailors of the seven seas) http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.5-sample-configuration.html

The following configuration worked for me (synced users and groups via JMX, successful login of a user, including auto sync):

**http://localhost:4502/apps/ldap-test.9.json**

```
  {
  "jcr:primaryType": "nt:folder",
  "config": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Folder",
    "org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authentication.ldap.impl.LdapIdentityProvider-test": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
      "provider.name": "ldap-test-alex",
      "host.name": "localhost",
      "host.port": "10389",
      "host.ssl": false,
      "host.tls": false,
      "bind.dn": "uid=admin,ou=system",
      "bind.password": "secret",
      "user.objectclass": "person",
      "user.baseDN": "ou=people,o=sevenSeas",
      "user.idAttribute": "uid",
      "group.objectclass": "groupOfUniqueNames",
      "group.baseDN": "ou=groups,o=sevenSeas",
      "group.nameAttribute": "cn",
      "group.memberAttribute": "uniquemember",
    },
    "org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.DefaultSyncHandler-test": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
      "handler.name": "ldap-sync-test-alex",
      "user.pathPrefix": "ldap-test",
      "group.pathPrefix": "ldap-test",
      "user.membershipNestingDepth": 1,
      "user.autoMembership": [
        "contributor"
      ],
      "user.propertyMapping": [
        "profile/email=mail",
        "profile/familyName=sn",
        "profile/givenName=givenName",
        "profile/aboutMe=description"
      ]
    },
    "org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModuleFactory-test": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "sling:OsgiConfig",
      "idp.name": "ldap-test-alex",
      "sync.handlerName": "ldap-sync-test-alex",
      "jaas.controlFlag": "SUFFICIENT",
      "jaas.ranking": "50"
    }
  }
}
```

Check, to have the following

- know or set the password for the test user
- set user.autoMembership to contributor (to see more than a white screen after a successful login)
- check the OSGi config in the Felix console, maybe you missed the type or mispelled a config option
- Check the log-file for hints

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex - I've configured the 3 osgi configs and I'm able to retrieve and display all LDAP users. But I'm not able to authenticate user-id/password to create a logon module.

Comment: I will check this tonight, and test it with Apache Directory Studio. But the difficult part is the connection with the LDAP. Retrieving the users already is great.

Comment: Have you adapted the names? They are some kind of id, to connect everything. In my example ldap-emea and sync-emea.

Comment: Maybe you post your configuration, and tell us which LDAP server you use?

Comment: Btw. your code sample works great for me, so I  can authenticate: except that I named the  provider differently `externalIdentityProviderManager.getProvider("ldap-test-alex");`

Comment: Did you used any encryption/hashing method before passing as credentials?
If not what LDAP server instance are you using? 
As Apache directory service is by default storing all password as SSHA hashed value.
I fear that may be the reason as well. Just need to confirm other wise.

Comment: No, I just used it as is. And I used your code example as is. And in the past I used it for at least 3 different LDAP server. But as you can sync the users via JMX (as I understood), the login via the Bind-DN is working. So it is not the password. I would say it is the user name, which is specified in `user.idAttribute`. This differs with each LDAP. Or you need a prefix (e.g. emea/myuser) - which happens often in large companies (if user id's are not unique across all regions or merged companies). What LDAP server you use? What is your OSGi configuration?

Comment: I've updated with configs. Also, I meant hashing of userPassword and not the bind.password. I'm using Apache Directory studio for local setup and to create users manually

Comment: I just can wildly guess. 1st) Have you tried to set the password for your test user manually? Maybe the import fails. 2nd) Have you tried it with another LDAP client? 3rd) Change the bind-dn to one of your users, and try to connect. If this works, it means at least your password is set correctly.

Comment: Can you add the following user to your ldap? It works for me. I can login in AEM, and I can authenticate with your code.

# userpassword is "pass"
#
version: 1

dn: cn=Alexander Berndt,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: top
cn: Alexander Berndt
description: This is a test
givenname: Alexander
sn: Berndt
uid: aberndt
mail: aberndt@example.com
userpassword: {SHA}nU4eI71bcnBGqeO0t9tXvY1u5oQ=

Comment: The above should be an ldif file, but the comments destroy the formatting. I think you will get it.

Comment: Btw. I imported you LDIF file, and I cannot authenticate these users too. So the error is the strange user. If I create one manually, it works.

Comment: This one works (reformat the file to an ldif again, password = "pass")

Comment: version: 1

dn: cn=Ronaldo2,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Ronaldo2
sn: Ronaldo
uid: christiano2
userPassword: {SHA256}10/w7o2juYBrGMh32/KbveULW9jk2tejpyUAD+uC6PE=

Comment: RESOLVED!!
Issue was regarding the user creation method in Apache directory studio.

If we create a user and provide any attribute in addition to 'cn', dn is created as - 
dn: cn=eden+sn=hazard+uid=eden,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com i.e. '+' separated attributes

but if we create user with just 'cn' and add other attibutes later, it works.

That's why you were able to authenticate your users and mine users were failing authentication.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/configuring-aem6-apache-directory-service.html - AEM documentaion that I used is NOT helpful

Comment: IMPORTANT for future references-
Another sample user:-

dn: cn=cristian,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: cristian
sn: bale
uid: cristian
userPassword: {SSHA}QSOFZWViatL5u5gT8vFCw1zIrWkRHJgrZ8BiEw==


Thanks Alex for your help.

Comment: Actually I read your question wrongly in the beginning. If you only want to authenticate programmatically, you don't need the ExternalLoginModuleFactory and the DefaultSyncHandler. You need that only if the users shall be imported as AEM users (e.g. for closed-user-groups or user-generated-content) or to log-in in AEM (e.g. as content-authors). A pure authenticate works without, and it is a security issue, if you don't need it.

Comment: I've refered [https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/oak-login.html] . Please check 'login()' method line 198 'externalUser = idp.authenticate(credentials); '